# change ctrrl+a keyboard shortcut (select all)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-tweaks

I want "super+a" to select all text in whatever text field I'm in. In other words, change the "ctrl-a" shortcut to be super+a.

Here's why: in gnome tweaks: I love the "emacs input" option. I come from mac, so I'm used to ctrl-a going to beginning of the line, ctl-e to the end, ctrl-n next line, etc.

However, if ctrl-a goes to beginning of the line, I need a keyboard shortcut so that I can select all text.

EDIT

For the record, I found a workaround to my immediate problems. After changing the google search terms I used, I found this: https://askubuntu.com/a/607920/52054 . However, "ctrl-/" is still a horrible shortcut, IMO, and I want it to be super-a

Comment: do you find a way please?

Answer (score 1):

One way is by using dconf-editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Under the /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings, you will find one to select all.

Or you can use xbindkeys.